# I have a scenario where 99 different values are there to select the check boxes. How to create a loop so that i can select the check boxes one by one

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where 99 different values are there to select the check boxes. How to create a loop so that i can select the check boxes one by one.

Below are the code you can see there are different values for every check boxes. Please provide your comment how i can apply loop to get all the checkbox selected one by one.

```html
<tr>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="ap" name="site"/>
        AP
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="ar" name="site"/>
        AR
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="avis_xml" name="site"/>
        AVIS_XML
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="ba" name="site"/>
        BA
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="cdm" name="site"/>
        CDM
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="ch" name="site"/>
        CH
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="cj" name="site"/>
        CJ
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="co" name="site"/>
        CO
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="crr" name="site"/>
        CRR
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input id="site" class="" type="checkbox" value="cst" name="site"/>
        CST
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi pArAs, I am planing to apply nested for loop but not sure how to implement it. If you provide some suggestion then it would be great help for me.

Comment: ok start with how would you identify a single checkbox and click on it? Can you provide a one line code for this?

Comment: public void commoncheckboxes(String value)
 {                                                                                                             List <WebElement>  selectcheckbox = elements.allWebElements(quickviewBean.getX_commoncheckbox());
  boolean isfound = false;
  for(WebElement cc: selectcheckbox)
  {
   if (cc.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(value))
   {
    cc.click();
    isfound = true;
    break;
   }
    
  }
  if(!isfound)
   keyword.logWarn("checkbox '"+value+"' is not exists.");

Comment: Above is for select one checkbox but i am planing to select more than 10 check boxes.

Comment: so whats the issue?.. you are doing it right ...just remove the `break;` then it would click for all the elements inside the `List<WebElement> selectcheckbox`

Comment: issue is i have to select 5 check boxes out of 99 and these 5 i have to pass through argument.

Comment: so its simple you can pass these 5 values as arugments and then you can read them as `args` array considering args is the name of array which is an attribute of main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way,
Assuming you have webdriver instance and you are using java.

```
java.util.List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElementsByXPath("//input[@type='checkbox']");
for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++){
 WebElement element=elements.get(i);
 element.click(); 
}
```

Tip:This is very basic question.You should study and try java+webdriver.

Comment: You should avoid spoon feeding. This way he/she won't learn anything. Let them show what they have done and then help them out.